# Powershell script which is executing batch file on remote machine is not executing the commands but printing them

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am on host computer and trying to execute a batch file on remote machine in trusted domain. I have tried the following code:

## Run the batch file on the remote machine

```
try {
    Invoke-Command -Session $newsession -Scriptblock {
        Invoke-Expression "C:\EES_Installer\db\Database\mdm.dal\data\dataloader.bat"
        #Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c C:\EES_Installer\db\Database\mdm.dal\data\dataloader.bat"
         & cmd.exe /c "C:\EES_Installer\db\Database\mdm.dal\data\dataloader.bat"
    } -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [Exception] {
    echo "Error while running the remote command", $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message
    Remove-PSSession $newsession
    exit 1
}
Remove-PSSession $newsession
```

The problem with this code is that it prints the content of the batch file instead of executing it. I don't know what's wrong with this script. In the code I have shown both way, I had tried: with **'Invoke-Expression'** and with **'&'** operator

Comment: `invoke-expression` executes a string with the PowerShell interpreter.  If you want to execute a batch file with the cmd interpreter, then the entire command is `cmd /c "c:\path\to\dataloader.bat"`.

Comment: I have tried this way but is not working, It does not throw any exception and only prints the content of file.

Comment: in the scriptblock, do you also `cd` into the directory containing the batch file?

Comment: No, I am not 'cd' -ing into the directory. It looks like this:                                        cmd /c "C:\EES_Installer\db\Database\mdm.dal\data\dataloader.bat"

Comment: @Kiran Cd'ing to the target directory and then Invoke-Expression is the solution. Posted the answer below. Could you please accept this question? Thanks

Comment: @rapport89 ...I am glad you got it working :)...since you posted the working solution i think you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Kiran Can you accept my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    Invoke-Command -Session $newsession -Scriptblock {
        cd C:\BES_Installer\db\Database\mdm.dal\data
        Invoke-Expression "cmd.exe /c dataloader.bat"
    } -ErrorAction Stop
} ......
```

Cd'ing to the target directory and then starting the application using cmd is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, neither Invoke-Expression or & should be needed. Specifying the full path to the batch file should invoke it.

```
try
{
    Invoke-Command -Session $newSession -ScriptBlock  {
        C:\EES_Installer\db\Database\mdm.dal\data\dataloader.bat
    } -ErrorAction Stop
}
...
```

Comment: I was originally trying the same but it does not work. The batch file works fine if execute it through cmd in the remote machine.